# Complex LinearLayout Children Positioning and Filling

Tags: android, xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40.00dp">

 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="40.00dp"
    android:layout_height="40.00dp"
    android:background="@drawable/photo"/>

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40.00dp"
    android:textSize="14.00sp" />

 <Button
    android:layout_width="54.40dp"
    android:layout_height="22.40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

The above code is to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do.
I would like the Image left, button right, and textview to fill the remaining space in the center.
How can i position the button to align right and ignore textview width?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use layout_weight="1" on the TextView.  the others will default to 0 (meaning don't add any of the extra space to them)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40.00dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40.00dp"
        android:layout_height="40.00dp"
        android:background="@drawable/photo"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40.00dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="14.00sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="54.40dp"
        android:layout_height="22.40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect! I never used or understood weight until now, Thanks